# How do I call on a function by either clicking the button or pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been learning ReactJS and made an app using [Web Dev Simplified's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQAHSlTtcmY). As a next step I would like to add a keyUp or event listener (whichever works best) so the enter key can be pressed to Add Todo OR by pressing the add button.

Here is the function that adds the input to the list.

```
function handleAddTodo(e) {
const name = todoNameRef.current.value
if (name === '') return
setTodos(prevTodos => {
  return [...prevTodos, { id: uuidv4(), name: name, complete: false}]
})
todoNameRef.current.value = null}
```

As I was looking for a solution, I found that hooks might do the trick, but I am not sure where or how to add one.

```
<button class="add" onClick={handleAddTodo}>Add ToDo</button>
```

And this is the button itself. I thought about adding onKeyup next to onClick but I don't know how to specify the enter key - as in I know it's keycode is 13 but I don't know how to relate that to the function.

Comment: The Enter key on what? You wouldn't need to handle keypress for a button. Is there an input or something?

Comment: The input is the item to be added to the todo list. Next to it is the button that adds it to the list. I want said button to add the item by either pressing the button itself or pressing the enter key.

Comment: When a button is acted upon via keyboard commands the `click` event still fires. You don't need to explicitly handle that.

Comment: then your keyup would go on the input. You will however need to wrap your handleAddTodo to support filtering keyUp events only to enter key.

Comment: Maybe that's where we're confused. Is focus on the input or the button when Enter is pressed?

Comment: I want the Add button and enter key to have the same function which is to add the input to the list

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is have a submit action.

Simply add a html form of type submit with action arround you input field and you are good to go.

Also change the button to type submit.

On pressing enter the form would be posted back.

Take a look here. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: That's a bit heavy-handed. A simple event handler would be better than a bunch of extra markup.

Comment: Maybe so, but using the default behavior, even with a little bit more markup, means simpler event handling logic.